# Client/Server java - connection refused

Tags: java, client-server

I'm trying to write basic client server. The code works fine when I'm using "localhost" and random port. The problems start when I run the server and the client from different hosts, and then I get "Connection Refused".
I searched for this problem and none of the solutions helped (Disable the firewall, run the server before the client, connection to the internet etc)

Again, the code works fine, my firend ran it and all works fine. The problem is probably with my computer. I have a router.

Thank you

Comment: It's possible your ISP is blocking whatever port you're using.  Try using a port like 80, assuming there are no other services there already.

Comment: Can you ping the other machine? Does your firewall allows inbound/outbound access to the required machines with the specified ports?